# ASP.NET Add a number/text input modal when selecting an option from a dropdown list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, selectlist

So I am tryin to figure out how to select an option from a dropdown list in ASP.net where when you select the option of "custom pricing", a modal pops up to enter a text amount and that amount becomes the value. So someone selects the custom price option, a number input modal should pop up, they enter their price, and it will show up in the "value" below where "custom pricing" is located. If someone can help me out that would be great!

```
                <div class="inputs">
                    <label asp-for="PriceMultiplier" asp-postfix=":"></label>
                    <select name="PriceMultiplier">
                        <option value="0">Hide Pricing</option>
                        <option value="1">Net Pricing</option>
                        <option value="2">2x</option>
                        <option value="2.5">2.5x</option>
                        <option value="3">3x</option>
                        <option value="{}">Custom Pricing</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using JavaScript. Add a `<script>` tag to your html and add this function. Also add `onchange="jsFunction(this.value);"` to the `<select>` tag. I have used a javascript promt for now but you can show and hide your model when the function is fired.

```js
function jsFunction(value) {
  if(value == 'custom'){
    var NewValue = prompt("Please enter your price");
    document.querySelector("[value='custom']").textContent = NewValue;
    document.querySelector("[value='custom']").value = NewValue;
  }
}
```

```html
  <select name="PriceMultiplier" onchange="jsFunction(this.value);">
    <option value="0">Hide Pricing</option>
    <option value="1">Net Pricing</option>
    <option value="2">2x</option>
    <option value="2.5">2.5x</option>
    <option value="3">3x</option>
    <option value="custom">Custom Pricing</option>
  </select>
```